# Android - Send SMS through the built-in SMS application

Tags: android, sms, default

In first place, I use the emulator to test this.
I want to open the default SMS application with the text of the message (sent as an argument) and allow the user to take the control from there (and the in-built app).
I use this code:

```
Button btnSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSMS);
    btnSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
            it.putExtra("sms_body", "text"); 
            it.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        }
    });
```

When I press the button nothing happens. I would expect the SMS default application to open, with the text and other fields that the user must fill, then send the message. Is this because of the emulator or my code? I also specified the permission in the manifest:

*<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing startActivity::

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
it.putExtra("sms_body", "text"); 
it.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(it);
```

or you can use the below code also::

```
String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

Comment: What a mess in my head! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Send SMS with Build-in SMS App:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

i.putExtra("address", "09090909; 092322424; 123456778");

i.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS Content");

i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

startActivity(i);
```